# Magento 2 : How to get giftcard product price from order?

Tags: magento2

`$product->getPrice()` is **0** for gift card product.

```
    $prduct_prices = null;
    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();

    $prduct_prices[] = array(

        'price'         => $product->getFinalPrice(),
        'regular_price' => $product->getPrice(),
        'special_price' => $product->getSpecialPrice(),
    );

}
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Do you want to get gift card product ?

Comment: Hello, I am getting order items from order, now i am trying to get the price of the product but with above methods on the gc product it returns 0

Comment: this solution is for magento 1.9x, check if something similar exists for m2 as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236263/magento-getting-giftcard-code-and-amount

Comment: Thanks @ManashviBirla. but $order->getGiftCardsAmount() will return the total amount of gc, i am trying to get that particular amount of price single gc product.

Comment: $order->getGiftCardsAmount() is also returning 0

Answer (score 0):

try below code

load first order and get getGiftCards data.

```
$cards = unserialize($_order->getGiftCards());
    if($cards!='' && count($cards)>0) {
        foreach ($cards as $card) {
             echo $card['c'];
             echo $card['a'];
    }
}
```

c means - gift code

a means - gift amount